# Hosting a web site at home: ISP Blocking port 80?

Tags: website, isp, web-hosting

I presume this is a better place to put this rather than server fault.

I'm interested in setting up a small site to host at home as a "proof of concept" exercise, i.e. to prove that I know how to do it. I've got a (virtual) server 2003 machine with a site on it, all configured with port forwarding through to 80 on my server. I have a Belkin F5D7634 which I have put my DYNDNS details in but when I try to go to my DYNDNS address it comes up with the page cannot be displayed.

My ISP is Carphone Warehouse/AOL and I've been unable to find any information if they block port 80. If they do, can anybody recomend a home provider that does not block port 80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More ISP's than not will block port 80 nowadays to prevent incoming traffic.  Usually they won't tell you they are blocking it and your odds of getting a straight or accurate answer if you call tech support are about 50/50.  Some ISP's will allow you to set up a server if you work with them to set it up (sometimes with additional monthly fees, sometimes not).  About the only way to find out is to call the various ISP's that serve your area and see what they say.  Oh, and call the tech support number, not the sales office.  The salespeople will either have no idea or they will just tell you what you want to hear.

Comment: The only thing I have to add is that you should try forwarding to and running the server on a different port (e.g. 8000) and connecting to that one instead. If it works, you know that port 80 is special, i.e., blocked.

Comment: +1 for the call tech support idea, much appriciated.

Comment: My isp just straight off says no ports are blocked, when all the ports are. Not really reliable unless you can catch them red handed by asking them to try open both your public and local ip on their computer.

Answer (score 4):

For testing, take DynDNS out of the list of possible problems:

1. Go to [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/).
2. Try that IP address directly, but: from some other internet connection, like by using [Web-Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/).
3. Try [an online traceroute](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/traceroute/) to that address (that will not use port 80, but might still give you some clue).

If that doesn't work, there are many possible causes other than port blocking, like:

- Maybe the port forwarding in the router is incorrect.
- You might be trying to use the DynDNS address (or public IP address) from within your own network, which will likely end up in your router rather than at the web server.
- Maybe (but not likely) you've set up your web server to only bind to localhost, not to any outside requests.

Comment: "You might be trying to use the DynDNS address (or public IP address) from within your own network, which will likely end up in your router rather than at the web server." The DSL router's I've used do this. If this is the case, use a proxy/someone else's line to get past it.

Comment: @Henri, or use Web-Sniffer and the like to test that (either with the IP address, or with the OpenDNS name).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to reply to this as I've now found the answer.

The problem was with the port forwarding of the router. Due to a bug in the firmware, it would only "remember" the TCP port setting, even when changed to UDP/TCP or just UDP. Following a firmware update I can choose to forward both types of port and it seems to be working. I am surpirsed that the ISP doesn't block port 80, but hey, I'm not going to complain.

Comment: A web server will use only TCP port 80. You shouldn't need to forward UDP as well.

Comment: @jmbouffoar this was before I knew about only using port 80 TCP, but thanks for adding the comment.